# Javascript project/multi-file editor for Linux

Tags: open-source, javascript, text-editor, source-code

I'm looking for a GUI editor for a collection of Javascript files, in a folder structure.

Required features:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Shows a tree-like view of elements in a script file - top-level entities, members within objects etc.
- Relatively low memory footprint
- Loads and responds reasonably fast even on somewhat old computers
- Syntax highlighting
- Actively maintained
- Runs on modern Linux distributions

Desired features:

- Can fuzzily lookup definitions of functions in other files, even if their relations is not formally or properly defined (otherwise I'd need it to be a full-fledged IDE with a bunch of complex logic).
- Supports light and dark color schemes
- Can also edit CSS and XML/XHTML/XUL files (with syntax highlighting and fuzzily finding definitions in other files)
- Runs on Windows
- Ongoing development
- Uses native GUI toolkits and doesn't "invent the wheel" UI-wise

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor (free). It has almost all the needed items. Except

- it has its own UI look
- it cannot find symbols in other JS files. But it can do it for the current file.

It has also the helper for JS coding - plugin Tern, for some intellisense.

Comment: 1. Link please? 2. Why is it called Cuda text? Does this have anything to do with NVIDIA CUDA, the GPU programming environment?

Answer (score 0):

I use VS Code and it ticks most of the boxes except for `Relatively low memory footprint`. If you avoid installing too many plugins, the memory shouldn't be a big deal.